# Found shape-key but no CD_SHAPEKEY layers to read from

Tags: error, shape-keys

Whenever I try to use [Separate > By Loose Parts] I get the next warning in the console

```
WARN (bmesh.mesh.convert): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v360\blender.git\source\blender\bmesh\intern\bmesh_mesh_convert.cc:917 bm_to_mesh_shape: Found shape-key but no CD_SHAPEKEY layers to read from, using existing shake-key data where possible
```

and the resulting object meshes gets a duplicate Shape Key named as the Basis Shape Key.

Example:

Original Object Mesh

```
Basis
Example
```

[image: Pre-Separate]

Resulting Object Meshes:

```
Basis
Example
Basis.001
```

[image: Post-Separate]

Tried:

- Exporting & Importing (Almost all formarts).
- Duplicating and repeating.
- Redoing the Shape Keys.
- [Separte] => [Join] => [Separte > By Loose] Manually. Separte itself doesn't cause to trigger this.
- New Blend file/project.
- Updated up to 3.6.4
- Downgraded down to 3.2.0

File:

[image]